# Iterate a list, assign a variable to each item and return it

Tags: python, loops, range, turtle-graphics

I'm having some difficulty with a project of mine. I'm trying to assign a variable to a list item, call the item and then repeat the process indefinitely. I'm doing this within Turtle.

The purpose of the code is to draw a coloured circle. Currently, I have it set up that it randomly chooses a colour from the list. I would rather it go through the list from start to end and repeatedly draw the next colour in the list.

```
import turtle as t
import random as r

# list of shades of blue
colourBlue = ['midnight blue', 'navy', 'cornflower blue', 'dark slate blue', 
'slate blue', 'medium slate blue', 'light slate blue', 'medium blue', 'royal 
blue', 'blue', 'dodger blue', 'deep sky blue']


# Call a colour from the list and draw a circle of said colour
def circle():
    t.pendown()
    t.begin_fill()        
    t.color(r.choice(colourBlue))
    t.circle(10)
    t.end_fill()
    t.penup()

# Defines a function that loops through ColourBlue list

def colourPick():
    colourBlueLen = len(colourBlue)
    for i in range(11, colourBlueLen):
        i = colourBlue[0]
```

So far I have established a way to select an item in the list but I'm uncertain as to how I should assign it to a variable, call it within the `t.color()` function and repeat the process throughout the list.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I managed to work out a solution with the help of a friend.

```
colourBlue = ['midnight blue', 'navy', 'cornflower blue', 'dark slate blue', 
'slate blue', 'medium slate blue', 'light slate blue', 'medium blue', 'royal 
blue', 'blue', 'dodger blue', 'deep sky blue']

currentColour = 0

# Establishes a function that calls a each colour from the list
def circle():
    t.pendown()
    t.begin_fill()        
    t.color(colourPick())
    t.circle(10)
    t.end_fill()
    t.penup()

def colourPick():
    global currentColour
    colourBlueLen = len(colourBlue)

    # If the last colour in the list has been used, reset it back to 0
    if currentColour == colourBlueLen:
        currentColour = 0

    colour = colourBlue[currentColour]

    # Increment currentColour values
    currentColour += 1

    return colour

circle()
```

Comment: You can use the modulus operator (`%`) instead of your `if` statement by doing `currentColour = (currentColour + 1) % len(colourBlue)` which will keep `currentColour` in the correct range.

Answer (score 1):

> I would rather it go through the list from start to end and repeatedly
>   draw the next colour

If you want to work through a list of colors in order, but don't want to be bound by the list itself, I recommend `itertools.cycle()`.  It will allow you to work your way through the list of colors over and over again as many times as you need without consideration for the actual number of colors:

```
from itertools import cycle
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

# list of shades of blue
BLUE_SHADES = cycle(['midnight blue', 'navy', 'cornflower blue', 'dark slate blue', \
    'slate blue', 'medium slate blue', 'light slate blue', 'medium blue', 'royal blue', \
    'blue', 'dodger blue', 'deep sky blue'])

# Call a colour from the list and draw a circle of said colour
def circle(turtle):
    turtle.color(next(BLUE_SHADES))
    turtle.begin_fill()
    turtle.circle(50)
    turtle.end_fill()

screen = Screen()

yertle = Turtle(visible=False)
yertle.speed('fastest')

for _ in range(120):
    circle(yertle)
    yertle.right(3)

screen.exitonclick()
```

[image]

If you'd rather just work througth the color list once, that's easy too.  Just use the color list itself as your iteration target:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

# list of shades of blue
BLUE_SHADES = ['midnight blue', 'navy', 'cornflower blue', 'dark slate blue', \
    'slate blue', 'medium slate blue', 'light slate blue', 'medium blue', 'royal blue', \
    'blue', 'dodger blue', 'deep sky blue']

# Call a colour from the list and draw a circle of said colour
def circle(turtle, color):
    turtle.color(color)
    turtle.begin_fill()
    turtle.circle(50)
    turtle.end_fill()

screen = Screen()

yertle = Turtle(visible=False)
yertle.speed('fastest')

for shade in BLUE_SHADES:
    circle(yertle, shade)
    yertle.right(360 / len(BLUE_SHADES))

screen.exitonclick()
```

[image]

Comment: That's awesome, thanks so much. I tried googling the solution and never came across itertools or the cycle function. Will definitely make use of it the future.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want to pass an argument to `circle`:

```
def colourPick():
    for c in colourBlue:
        circle(c)
```

and then use that parameter instead of `r.choice(colourBlue)`.